# I want to forecast a NetCDF data

Tags: dataset, lstm, forecasting

I have a chlorophyl-a and sea surface temp (SST) in a NetCDF format, the data is 4 dimensional mattrix, each data is saved inside certain longitude and lattitude value, if the data plotted into heatmap it looked like this [enter image description here][image].

and this is how the data look like [image]

I want to forecast all the time series in this data using LSTM, but there is 31 lattitaude and 19 longitude so there is a lot of data, so instead of making model for every point of longitude and lattiude I intent to use a sample. but how do I took sample of this data

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense,Dropout

ds = xr.open_datset("your_file")
ds = ds.stack(z=("latitude","longitude"))
data_variable = "your_variable"
data = np.array(ds.data_variable.values)
data = data.T
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0],data.shape[1],1)
time_steps = data.shape[1]-1

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[:, :-1, :], data[:, -1, :], test_size=0.2)
```

#### Normalize the data

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(X_test.shape)
y_train = scaler.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(y_train.shape)
y_test = scaler.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(y_test.shape)
```

#### Build LSTM model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=100, input_shape=(time_steps, 1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units = 100))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

#### Train the model

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

#### Evaluate the model

```
loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("Test loss:", loss)
```

#### Make predictions

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

#### Rescale predictions and actual values to original scale

```
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
actual_values = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
```

#### Print predictions and actual values

```
rmse = np.sqrt(((predictions-actual_values)**2).mean())
rmse
```